# What does it mean for a scheme to be proper?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

What exactly does it mean for a scheme to be proper? I can't seem to find an actual definition of this anyway despite the term being frequently used.

Comment: Did you look in the standard references? Hartshorne certainly defines properness (of a morphism!)

Comment: I can find references for morphisms but it's not quite clear of precisely the condition for a scheme itself to be proper.

Comment: That is because properness is a relative condition. You always have to define it with respect to some base scheme. (As the answer below suggests, if the base is not mentioned explicitly, then it is usually spec of the integers, and the morphism is the canonical one. The same is true more generally for other properties.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A scheme $X$ over a ring $A$ is said to be proper if its structural morphism $f:X\rightarrow\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is a proper morphism of schemes. I think our subject is just that way that one just states it for the relative case (i.e. for morphisms), and omits the definitions in the "absolute" case (where it is just the relative case applied to the structural morphism).

In the most general situation one says that a scheme $X$ over a base scheme $S$ is proper if the structural morphism $X\rightarrow S$ is proper. Actually at this generality it becomes clear (if it wasn't clear before) that you should think of "$X$ over $S$" as the same thing as a morphism $X\rightarrow S$. It is just a different use of language.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense! The part about the structural morphism and $Spec(A)$ was what I needed.

Comment: @Rhoswyn More generally, if you look up some term in Hartshorne and it is only applied to morphisms, then a scheme is said to have the property if the structural morphism has it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah, okay that's useful to know, thanks.

Comment: Very good point Tobias, I was actually adding exactly this when you wrote that comment.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the edit appearing at about the same time I submitted the comment.